# How to create a layer over a surface with mayavi?

Tags: python, gdal, 3d, surface

I made a program with python which displays an animation of the propagation of a fire spreading in a forest in 2D (the forest is an array):

- no tree = 0.0
- a tree = 1.0
- a tree in fire = 2.0

Here is an example (without wind and relief):

[image]

And I also made a surface plot with mayavi, python and gdal using this post ([DEM plot with matplotlib is too slow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223129/dem-plot-with-matplotlib-is-too-slow)).

Now I want to know how to put the propagation that I made with an array (in 2D) over the surface of the mountain as if it was a kind of layer that will be able to move and grow on the surface like a fire growing in a forest.

I am not asking for an algorithm that can make a simulation of a forest fire.

I am asking for a way to create this kind of layer over the surface plot I made.

For instance, in the next photo you can see a red layer (the spreading fire) on the surface:

[image]

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/48202796_fig11_Fig-11-The-finest-domain-in-the-Meadow-Creek-fire-simulation-5-h-after-ignition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but for me it is not a GIS problem but a pure Python problem:

1. You need to learn [Mayavi: mlab: Python scripting for 3D plotting](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) before using it.
2. Mayavi, as Matplotlib, knows nothing about georeferenced surfaces. You can plot easily a DEM surface, but if you want to drape a raster over the DEM or plot lines, it is a problem of Mayavi.
3. The only example I know is [3D terrain visualization with python and Mayavi2](http://geoexamples.blogspot.be/2014/02/3d-terrain-visualization-with-python.html)

Generally, I use GRASS GIS for that with also [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/) witch also use [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also found this example but this is an image not an array and it does not say how to cover the DEM with my animation of a forest fire. I will look at your first link and learn everything I can but I do not think I will be able to do this on my own. I hope that someone else knows these kind of things. Thank you for your help :)